# FFMpeg-PHP, Digital Ocean, Centos 6 server installation and access

Tags: ffmpeg, centos, centos6, digital-ocean, ffmpeg-php

I am having problems getting FFMpegPHP up and running on a Digital Ocean, Centos 6 server.

All I need to do is convert a sequence of images into a movie using PHP.

I have FTP access to my server so I can install files if needed, I also have command line access.

I have installed FFMpeg and FFMpeg-PHP onto the server but I am not sure how to execute it from PHP. This is what I have so far ->

http://socialexplosion.co.uk/phpffmpeg/

This is the output from the error-log:

```
[24.02.16 15:28:07] [131.231.236.97] Invalid FFMPEG Path `/var/www/html/phpffmpeg/ffmpeg\bin\ffmpeg.exe`! 
[24.02.16 15:28:09] [131.231.236.97] ffmpeg-progress: FFMPEG progress log does not exist! FILE: `/var/www/html/phpffmpeg/logs/47fc097c.ffmpeg.log`
```

I can't seem to get it to work.

Any ideas? Maybe I have installed it wrong?

Thanks